# Objetos literales dentro de una clase ¿Como acceder?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase, donde nos ha pedido hacer una clase alumno con tres variables, una de ellas un objeto literal, mi pregunta es a la hora de acceder a ese objeto literal para poder cambiar los paramentros, es decir, como cambiar el AlumnoPrueba.notas.matematicas?  como se hace? Por que al hacer esto me dice que matematicas no está definido.

Os dejo lo que tengo hecho

```
class Alumno {
    constructor(nombre, apellido, notas) {
        this._nombre = nombre || 'Sin nombre',
            this._apellido = apellido || 'Sin apellido',
            this._notas = notas || {
                Matematicas: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Lengua: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Fisica: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Ingles: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
                Musica: generaAleatorio(0, 10)
            }

    }
}

function generaAleatorio(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

}
var AlumnoPrueba = new Alumno();
AlumnoPrueba.nombre = "Paco";
AlumnoPrueba.apellido = "Martinez";
AlumnoPrueba.notas;
console.log(AlumnoPrueba);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes inconsistencias en tu código, lo correcto sería acceder con

```
AlumnoPruebas._notas.Matematicas
```

Porque Javascript diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, y se te ha olvidado el `_` que has usado al declarar la propiedad.

```js
class Alumno {
    constructor(nombre, apellido, notas) {
        this._nombre = nombre || 'Sin nombre';
        this._apellido = apellido || 'Sin apellido';
        this._notas = notas || {
            Matematicas: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
            Lengua: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
            Fisica: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
            Ingles: generaAleatorio(0, 10),
            Musica: generaAleatorio(0, 10)
        };

    }
}

function generaAleatorio(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

}
let AlumnoPrueba = new Alumno(); //esto crearía un alumno sin nombre
//estás añadiendo una propiedad distinta a la que añade constructor, te falta el _ delante
AlumnoPrueba.nombre = "Paco";
//de nuevo falta el _
AlumnoPrueba.apellido = "Martinez"; 
AlumnoPrueba.notas; //esto no hace nada!

//Lo que realmente tienes
console.log(JSON.stringify(AlumnoPrueba,null,2));

//Algo más correcto
let alumno2= new Alumno("Paco","Martinez");
console.log('En Mates', alumno2._nombre,'tiene un',alumno2._notas.Matematicas);
```

Comment: Gracias tio....estoy cieguisimo.